# Get data in React child component's to parent for submission

Tags: reactjs

I was just wondering how I can get form data when a user submits I want to be able to see it in the console.log Here is what my parent component looks like.

```
class App extends Component {

       render() {

         return (

      <div className="App">

      <PageOne /> 
      <PageTwo />
      <PageThree />
      <PageFour />
      <PageFive />
      <PageSix />

      <Button>
         Submit Form
      </Button>

      <br/>
      <br/>



      </div>

        );
      }
     }



Page One Component 



          class PageOne extends Component {
 
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
         generalDetails: '',
          phoneNumber: '',
         fName: '',
         mName: '',
         lName: '',
         gender: '',


        }
       this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);


      }


     handleInputChange(event) {
       const target = event.target;
       const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : 
     target.value;
       const name = target.name;


       console.log(`Input name ${name}. Input value ${value}.`);

       this.setState({
         [name]: value
       });
     }




       render() {
         return (
           <div className="PageOneWrapper"
              style={{
               background: '#969fad'
           }}


      >
      <div className="Details">

      <h1>CareerTrackers Program Orientation</h1>
      <p> Please complete this form to ensure we have your most up-to-date contact details. </p>

      <Form>
  <TextArea
  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
  name="generalDetails"
  placeholder='General Details'
   style={{
  width: 500,
  minHeight: 50
  }}
  />
  </Form>
<br/>

<p style={{
  marginRight: 600

        <Input
      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
      name='fName'
       placeholder='First Name'
            />








  <Input
      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
      name='mName'

       placeholder='Middle Name'
       style={{
         marginLeft: 50,
         marginRight: 50
       }}
       />


       <Input
       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
       name='lName'
       placeholder='Last Name'
       />

       <br/><br/><br/>

      <p
      style={{
        display: "inline",
        marginRight: 480
      }}
    ><strong>Gender: </strong>


     </p>
     <select
     name='gender'
     onChange={this.handleInputChange}
     style={{
       display: "inline",
     }}
     >
     <option>Select Gender </option>
     <option>Male </option>
     <option>Female </option>
     <option>Other </option>
     </select>



       <br/><br/><br/>


       <p style={{
         marginRight: 600

       }}><strong>Email:</strong></p>

       <Input
       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            name='email'
            placeholder='Email'
            style={{
              marginRight: 470,

            }}
            />
            <br/>
            <br/>
       <Input
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}

            name='confirmEmail'
            placeholder='Confirm Email'
            style={{
              marginRight: 470,

            }}
            />

            <br/>
            <br/>

            <p style={{
              marginRight: 540


            }}><strong>Phone Number:</strong></p>




       <Input
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            name='phoneNumber'
            placeholder='Phone Number'
            style={{
              marginRight:370,
            }}
            />





            <select
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            name='Mobile Type'
            style={{
              MarginRight: 5000
            }}

            >
            <option>Mobile Type</option>
            <option>Mobile</option>
            <option>Work</option>
            <option>Home</option>

            </select>




            <br/>
            <br/>



<br/><br/><br/>



</div>
  </div>

          );
       }
     }
        export default PageOne;
```

Comment: You need to pass a function as a props from parent component to child component.
In this case, this.handleChange() function must be declared in parent and pass as props to child. You can use it in child like this.props.handleChange. Maintain values of all the form in parent state. Similarly, you can also pass handle submit function via props from parent. Since parent have all data you can submit your form.

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to provide me with an example if possible? I'm quite new to this!

Answer (score 1):

`const handleChange=(data)=>{console.log(data)}`

Add this function to your parent component.

Pass this function to your child component like `<PageOne handleChane={handleChange}/>`

You can now access the function in your child component through props.

Call the function like `onSubmit={this.props.handleChnage()}` and pass the required data as parameter.

If you don't have a submit button in the child components, you need to define each of the `onChange` handle functions in  your parent component and pass them to respective child components as previously mentioned. Then you get the value of form elements in your parent component.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to be a pain, but could you please provide me an example on how to define the onChange handle functions in my parent component and pass them througfh to the child components?

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jsv0qp7/). I have used only one component. Use the method for the multiple components that you have. Pass the required function to the respective child component.

Answer (score 0):

**In Parent Component Change code as mention below:**

```
<PageOne />  should be <PageOne onDataChange={(content) => this.onContentChange(content)}/>
```

And add onContentChange function in parent component like below:

```
onContentChange = (content) => {
   //Perform operation What you want to do with updated content
}
```

**In Child Component Update code as mention below:**

```
 Add below line of code at the end of handleInputChange function definition:

if(this.props.onDataChange){
  this.props.onDataChange(this.state); // You can pass limited data if you don't want to send all data to parent. What data need to sent is completely depends on your requirements.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What shold I do with the   <Button >
         Submit Form
      </Button> 

am I doing something like 

<button onSubmit={this.props.onContentChange()}

Comment: No need to add any changes on **Submit Form** button as that button is on parent component. ** this.props.onDataChange()** you need to call in child component when ever you want to pass data to parent component from child component.

Comment: In ** onContentChange ** you can add your own logic , based on what you want to do with updated received data from child. **onContentChange** function will be call when ever and data change in PageOne component.